# Markercluster toggle ON / OFF

Tags: leaflet

They asked me for a 'toggle button' to switch the clustering on and off Can someone help me to achieve clustering on/off?

Note: loading more than 30,000 points

Comment: Since this question was posted, I made the [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable) subplugin that provides this exact feature. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142197/with-leaflet-markercluster-how-can-i-switch-between-clustered-and-unclustered-w

Answer (score 4):

Create two layers, one with and one without the marker clustering and add them to the leaflet control. For example:

```
var littleton = L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.'),
denver    = L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.'),
aurora    = L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.'),
golden    = L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.');

var cities = L.layerGroup([littleton, denver, aurora, golden]);

var citiesClustered = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
markers.addLayer(littleton);
markers.addLayer(denver);
markers.addLayer(aurora);
markers.addLayer(golden);

var streets   = L.tileLayer(mapboxUrl, {id: 'examples.map-i86knfo3', attribution: mapboxAttribution});
var map = L.map('map', {
center: [39.73, -104.99],
zoom: 10,
layers: [streets, cities]
});

var baseMaps = {
"Streets": streets
};

var overlayMaps = {
"Cities": cities,
"Clustered cities": citiesClustered
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

You can also create a custom control that will de-cluster the markers but this control already exists and it's easy to implement.

Comment: It's only terribly slow. I've to wait again after switching between markers and cluster (even if they've loaded before) Is it possible to load them on beforehand and only show them when selected

Comment: and/or show marker overlay option only at a certain zoom level >

Comment: 1. Well marker cluster has an option in it to de-cluster the markers on a specified zoom level. This is one way to go without the layer control.
2. The other way to go is to create a custom leaflet control and to de cluster the markers on the click. You can enable/disable the control based on the current zoom level of course.

Comment: I'm aware of the option to de-cluster the markers on a specified zoom level. But (as far as I know) you can't change it dynamically. Option 2 is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Reviving this two years later. This kind of workaround causes a whole lot of problems if the markers are moving. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/635#issuecomment-271186191