# With Leaflet markercluster, how can I switch between clustered and unclustered without changing zoom level?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using the [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin to cluster my points.

However, users are asking for the functionality to switch between clustered and unclustered views (basically, they want to see all their points at a high zoom).

I know that I can disable clustering at a specific zoom level:

```
markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    disableClusteringAtZoom: 8,
})
```

How can I force everything to uncluster when I am further zoomed out, though?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would probably be interested in [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable plugin](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable).

It provides extra methods on Leaflet.markercluster, including `disableClustering()` and `enableClustering()`, which enable you to uncluster / cluster programmatically (e.g. on a button click) without needing the user to zoom in/out.

See also the plugin [demo page](https://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable/examples/mcg-freezable.html).

Of course, you should be careful whenever you call `disableClustering()`, since you may instantly load **all** your markers on map (if you are zoomed out to their full extent). If that tries loading thousands of markers, you may freeze your browser or even crash it.

> Disclaimer: I am the author of this plugin.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I think I can implement enableClustering() and disableClustering() in my app on my own. ♥️