# Toggle Leaflet.markercluster on/off at runtime?

Tags: leaflet

Having looked through the documentation, I cannot find any way to essentially "turn off" the marker clustering at runtime. I want a checkbox for this in that little GUI menu that we probably all have in Leaflet.js. Can it be done easily and nicely? Would be useful. Sometimes I don't want it to cluster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Leaflet markercluster, how can I switch between clustered and unclustered without changing zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142197/with-leaflet-markercluster-how-can-i-switch-between-clustered-and-unclustered-w)

Answer (score 3):

Create a `L.LayerGroup` in addition to the `L.MarkerClusterGroup`. Add all your markers to both. When adding the marker cluster group, remove the non-clustered layergroup, and vice versa.

Comment: That will certainly kill the last bit of performance... which I was trying to *save*... There's got to be a proper way, no?